# UItextField not letting to enter zero

Tags: swift, uitextfield

HOW TO NOT let user enter more than one zero at the start of the calculation in the UItextfield. for example open your calculator app in your iPhone it won't let you enter more than one zero. How can I do that in swift. Thank you in advance.